# Transparent form

Tags: c#, controls, transparent

I in c# froms have transparent properties. When I set 0.5 value of form's opacity, also all controls opacity set 0.5 too. I just want from, not all controls , All controls must still full view.

Is it possible? if yes how ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the TransparencyKey property and back color of the form as same.